# WPF ListBoxItem IsMouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, ismouseover

I have a ListBox, which on mousing over an item shows a delete button for that item. The problem is that the IsMouseOver triggers about 4 pixels into the highlighted item, so when mousing over multiple items, instead of the delete button seeming to move up and down with you, it flickers in the gaps between the items. Is there anyway to make IsMouseOver respond to the whole item?

```
<ListBox Name="lstLength" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource lengths}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="22">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="btnDelete" Content="X" Tag="{Binding}" Click="DeleteLength" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DockPanel>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="btnDelete" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each one of your items will be contained within a `ListBoxItem`, this is what gives the ~4 pixels between each item. It also provides the highlight and selection styling. You can style the `listBoxItem` via the [ListBox.ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. Move your trigger to the item container and it should work as desired.

Comment: The TargetName can't be set on a Style Setter apparently

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DataTrigger` directly on the button (or try to apply the same `RelativeSource` binding in the place it is):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                 Value="True">
          <!-- ... -->
    </DataTrigger>
</Style>
```

Comment: I was hoping to make the whole item respond to mouse over rather than just the button

Comment: @Mim Huford: In your own code you only change something on the button, this does the same thing. Where a DataTrigger is placed has little to with what it responds to. (And as i said, you can also leave it in the `Template.Triggers`.)